# Is using a TextView to create separation between two page elements ill-advised?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

I'm a student in an android development program.  I've built a few apps and I had an idea to use a very simple `TextView` to draw a line across the screen to visually separate a page element.  The `TextView` would hold no text, it has no function or use other than to separate two elements with a horizontal rule.  I'm using it in a `ConstraintLayout`.

Can anyone give me a reason as to why this is NOT a good idea?  What would the best practices be otherwise? Is it normal to use an empty `TextView` in this manner?

[image]

Comment: Naaa, use a Frame layout and width match parent, height what you need and set the background color or drawable you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to do that, but it's unnecessary to use a `TextView` specifically: A `TextView` with no text is just a `View`.

You can just create a `View` with whatever height and background color and use that:

```xml
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="@color/my_divider_color" />
```

Replace `1dp` with whatever height you want and `@color/my_divider_color` with whatever color you want the divider to be.